# How to copy one folder to all other subfolders of a folder?

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory

I want to copy folder `IMAGE` to all other folders in a folder.

The folder structure is:

- **Test folder**

  - FirstSubFolder
  - **IMAGE**
  - OneMoreSubFolder
  - Test Folder 1
  - TestFolder2

The result should be:

- **Test folder**

  - FirstSubFolder

    - **IMAGE**
  - **IMAGE**
  - OneMoreSubFolder

    - **IMAGE**
  - Test Folder 1

    - **IMAGE**
  - TestFolder2

    - **IMAGE**

Which commands do I need in a batch script to do this folder copying task?

Answer (score 0):

With `Test folder` being the current directory use following batch code:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in (*) do (
    if /I not "%%D" == "IMAGE" (
        xcopy "IMAGE\*" "%%D\IMAGE\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
    )
)
```

Or if just the files and subfolders in `IMAGE` should be copied to all other subfolders of `Test folder`, use this code:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in (*) do (
    if /I not "%%D" == "IMAGE" (
        xcopy "IMAGE\*" "%%D\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
    )
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `xcopy /?`